# Mediator pattern for flip animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My apps design should allow for the user to choose, which of the two views does he/she prefers. The animation between the two views should be UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal. 
The problem/question is which one of them is the modal controller. I don't want any of them to be. 
Actually I want to have a rootViewController that would take care about the flip animation and would serve as a mediator.

Can this be done? Any advice?

Comment: please be clear you are presenting your new view as modal view controller right?

Comment: its a theoretical question. I have not written code yet.
To rephrase, normally one VC is the parent , and the other one is modally presented, using the flip animation. What I want is to have a mediator class that would help me to animate to the other controller, whichever it would be. The reason is, both VCs are equally important so there is no preferred one to be the parent VC and the other one to be modal one.

Comment: without presenting it modally you change rootviewconroller at runtime that would so simpler

Comment: HM..interesting..I'l try that approach today, and see how it works... then let you know.

Comment: can i post any answer relating to that